# Trying to set an image to change at certain times on a loop Monday-Friday

Tags: javascript

I am wanting the below to run Monday-Friday and on the weekends display the second image (4:30pm-:8:30am) on a constant loop.

The image will display when a customer service team is available Monday-Friday 8:30am-4:30pm and will display when they are not available outside of these hours.

However I wish for it to display just `} else { document.write('<img src="#IMAGE 4:30PM-8:30AM#">');` on Saturday and Sunday

```js
var now = new Date();
var today = now.getDay();
var startTime = new Date();
startTime.setHours(08);
startTime.setMinutes(30);
startTime.setSeconds(00);
var endTime = new Date();
endTime.setHours(16);
endTime.setMinutes(30);
endTime.setSeconds(00);
console.log(startTime,now,endTime)
if (today > 0 && today < 6) {
  if (startTime < now && endTime > now) {
    document.write('<img src="#IMAGE 08:30AM-4:30PM#">');
  } else {
    document.write('<img src="#IMAGE 4:30PM-8:30AM#">');
  }
}
```

Comment: Apart from not working in a different timezone than yours, what seems to be the issue?

Comment: Hello mplungjan, the script works perfect however it still runs on Saturday and Sunday. I wish for it to display just "  } else {
    document.write('<img src="#IMAGE 4:30PM-8:30AM#">');" on Saturday and Sunday

Comment: Hi Liam, welcome to Stackoverflow. You will find many people willing to anser your questions on this site. In order for us to help you, you need to formulate clearly your question? There doesn't seem to be one in your post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean this?

```js
var now = new Date(), startTime = new Date(), endTime = new Date();
var today = now.getDay();
var closedSign = 'image.ibb.co/mMAptU/if_18_Closed_Sign_1871435.png';
var openSign = 'image.ibb.co/f4rvYU/if_15_Open_Sign_1871431.png';

startTime.setHours(8, 30, 0);
endTime.setHours(16, 30, 0);

// open when now is within start and endTime, Mon to Fri
var src = (today > 0 && today < 6) &&
  (now >= startTime && now <= endTime) ? openSign : closedSign; // ternary

document.write('<img src="' + src + '">');
```

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
var now = new Date();
var today = now.getDay();
var startTime = new Date();
var src = "https://image.ibb.co/mMAptU/if_18_Closed_Sign_1871435.png"; // all other times than tested below
startTime.setHours(08);
startTime.setMinutes(30);
startTime.setSeconds(00);
var endTime = new Date();
endTime.setHours(16);
endTime.setMinutes(30);
endTime.setSeconds(00);

if ((today > 0 && today < 6) && (now >= startTime && now <= endTime))  {
  src = 'https://image.ibb.co/f4rvYU/if_15_Open_Sign_1871431.png';
}
document.write('<img src="' + src + '">');
</script>

Comment: Sorry for the formatting. So this code would run the closed sign on Satuday, Sunday and Monday-Friday 4:30pm-8:30am? and the other times Monday-Friday 8:30am-4:30pm it will run the open sign?

Sorry for being a newbie - appreciate the help!

Comment: My code will show 8:30-4:30 mon-fri 8:30 to 16:30 and at all other times the other image. Did you try? Please do not post code in comments

Comment: @LiamHannigan I have simplified it further